# Moving files to memory card

Tags: file-transfer, es-file-explorer

I am unable to move files to my memory card from phone.
[image: file transfer failed in memory card]

Htc 620g 
Android 4.4.2
Memory card 32 Gb
Please let me know what to do in this situation.there is 31 Gb free space in memory card.
[image]

Comment: try an Internal File Manager

Comment: Tried files did not moved

Comment: added another image

Comment: are you rooted by the way? There is a workaround for rooted devices